# sending encrypted email

Tags: iphone, email, encryption

I am currently sending an email from my xcode/iphone app.  The requirements are to send an encrypted email or attached file and then be able to decrypt/open the information after receipient delivery.

Has anyone seen any code to help me accomplish this task?

Thanks

Leland

Comment: Insufficient data on requirements to assist.  ?'s -  Is this for internal use, or do you need these emails to go to people/apps other than yours?  Might SSL be enough?  What sort of mail clients on the receiving end do you need to support?

Comment: good questions... the email should be able to go to any person's email client and not on a network.  Mail clients include gmail, hotmail, webmail any sort of client to receive emails.

Comment: Do Gmail and the rest natively support encryption/decryption?

Comment: I don't think so.. I'm thinking that the email needs to be an attachement and require a password to open it... but I'm looking for other people's experience on this one...

Comment: excuse me, have an attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you've quite thought this one through. In general, if an email client or webmail system does not have a feature to *send* an encrypted email (in any way), then you can be pretty sure that it also does not have a feature to *read* encrypted emails. For example, Gmail does not have a "send as encrypted" option, so sending any kind of encrypted email to Gmail will not be readable without using a separate decryption program.

There are two de facto standards for encrypting email, and lots of information about them both can be found on the page [S/MIME and OpenPGP](http://www.imc.org/smime-pgpmime.html). However, neither of these solutions offer a generally available email encryption facility. The level of interoperability between different systems is terrible, and no progress appears to be happening today.

One approach might be [Hushmail](http://hushmail.com) which has been around for a long time and is essentially its own encrypted webmail provider. You would email a Hushmail link to the user, they would click on that and go to the Hushmail site where they could read the email.

Answer (score 1):

[CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CryptoExercise/index.html) will give you tools to encrypt and decrypt. You'd need to do the UI work yourself.

Comment: Thanks, have you used this?  Do you think it will work on a non apple email or webmail client?

Comment: No, this a framework for applying cryptographic functions to data. You would add this to your application, to perform cryptographic operations. Gmail, etc. have no native support for such operations, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Use S/MIME, so that you don't need a specialized client on the receiving end.

Not sure if iPhone has an app for that, though.